# c++ class not declared in scope - called from main

Tags: c++, object, scope, program-entry-point

been stuck for quite a while now. Any help would be much appreciated.

FlexStringDemo.cpp - main

```
#include "FlexString.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    FlexString inputOne;
    return 0;
}
```

FlexString.h

```
#ifndef FLEXSTRING_H
#define FLEXSTRING_H

#include "LinkedList.h"
namespace linkedList{

class FlexString{

    public:
        FlexString();
        FlexString(std::string input);
    private:
        LinkedList *list;
        std::string data;

};
}
#endif
```

FlexString.cpp

```
#include "FlexString.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace linkedList{

FlexString::FlexString(){
    list = new LinkedList();
}

FlexString::FlexString(string input){
    list = new LinkedList();
}

}
```

I get this error message:

```
FlexStringDemo.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
```

FlexStringDemo.cpp:14:2: error: ‘FlexString’ was not declared in this scope
  FlexString inputOne;
  ^
    FlexStringDemo.cpp:14:2: note: suggested alternative:
    In file included from FlexStringDemo.cpp:1:0:
    FlexString.h:7:7: note:   ‘linkedList::FlexString’
     class FlexString{

No idea why i cant create a FlexString object as i have included the header file.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FlexString` belongs to the namespace `linkedList`.

You have to use scope resolution to access the class, like this

```
linkedList::FlexString inputOne;
```

Or the `using` keyword to omit the namespace

```
using namespace linkedList;
```

Though I recommend against the latter. Writing the namespace explicity is best.